# How to concat a local array from a loop into a local array outside loop?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, recursion

I have a basic recursive function that should push each value found in each array/object into the results array:

```
var bigArray = ['a', ['howdy', 'partner'], ['b', ['c', ['d', {a:'e', b:['yes', 'no', {apple: 'orange'}]}]]]];

function bagger293(bigArray){
  var results = [];
  for (var item in bigArray){
    if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object'){
      bagger293(bigArray[item]);
    }else{
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(bagger293(bigArray));
```

expectation: `[ 'a', 'howdy', 'partner', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'yes', 'no', 'orange' ]`

But since `var results = [];` is inside the function, everytime the recursion occurs, calling the function, the results array is changed, instead of added to over each loop. I know I need to concat, but I'm not sure how. I've tried `results.concat(results.push(bigArray[item]);` but that only returns `['a']`

If I move `var results = [];` to the global scope, it all works perfectly without the need for concat, but I want to achieve this at the local scope. Any ideas?

Comment: You concat the results of the recursive call of bagger293 to the results variable.

Comment: [`results = results.concat(bagger293(bigArray[item]));`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: This actually makes sense, yet produces 
```for (var item in bigArray){
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded```

Comment: @melpomene you should make an answer out of that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing would be to pass the result array along with the function:

```
function bagger293(bigArray, results) {
  for (var item in bigArray){
    if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object') {
      results = bagger293(bigArray[item], results);
    } else {
      results.push(bigArray[item]);
    }
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(bagger293(bigArray, []));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to achive the result.

```js
function x(r,a) {
    if (Array.isArray(a)) {
        return a.reduce(x, r);
    }
    if (a && typeof a === 'object') {
        return Object.keys(a).map(function (b) { return a[b]; }).reduce(x, r);
    }
    r.push(a);
    return r;
}

var bigArray = ['a', ['howdy', 'partner'], ['b', ['c', ['d', { a: 'e', b: ['yes', 'no', { apple: 'orange' }] }]]]],
    result = bigArray.reduce(x, []);
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always pass your results into your function as well.

```
function bagger293(bigArray, results) {
    // If results is passed, it will stay with that data. If it is not passed, it will be a new array.
    results = results || []; 

    for (var item in bigArray){
        if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object'){
          bagger293(bigArray[item], results);
        }else{
          results.push(bigArray[item]);
        }
      }

      return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare results as a member of bagger293 and initialize it only if it is void.

```
var bigArray = ['a', ['howdy', 'partner'], ['b', ['c', ['d', {a:'e', b:['yes', 'no', {apple: 'orange'}]}]]]];

function bagger293(bigArray){
bagger293.results = bagger293.results || [];
for (var item in bigArray){
  if (typeof bigArray[item] === 'object'){
    bagger293(bigArray[item]);
  }else{
    bagger293.results.push(bigArray[item]);
  }
}
  return bagger293.results;
}

console.log(bagger293(bigArray));
```

Outputs: ["a", "howdy", "partner", "b", "c", "d", "e", "yes", "no", "orange"]